# Multi-machine boot problem?

Tags: boot, uefi

How do I install Ubuntu 16 LTS on to a hard drive so that it can be used from different yet identical Laptops?

I have a couple of identical laptops at home and a number of hard drives.  When someone needs a laptop, I can just grab one no-one is using slide their hard drive in and give it to them for a while.  This has worked well for Ubuntu 14 LTS.

I tried doing a clean install of Ubuntu 16 LTS.  It seems to work great on the laptop I used to install the OS.  But if that laptop is taken and I put it into an identical laptop, Ubuntu 16 LTS won't boot.  I get the error "No bootable device".  If I launch the one-time boot menu, I see "ubuntu" listed under UEFI BOOT.  If I select this, I get "Selected boot device failed"

How do I install Ubuntu 16 LTS on to a hard drive so that it can be used from different yet identical Laptops?

Comment: did you try with secure boot off?

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu in UEFI mode all of these laptops should use the hard drive in UEFI. And vice versa if Ubuntu is installed in BIOS mode you should use it in this mode on all laptops.

Comment: I set two identical laptops side by side.  I confirmed that each of the bios settings are identical.  I confirmed that secure boot is and has been off.  I booted up both fine using UEFI and Ubuntu 16 LTS.  I shut them down and swapped harddrives.  Both computers give me the same error mentioned above.  Any other ideas why Ubuntu 14 LTS worked and Ubuntu 16 LTS doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

There must be some unique key or some other difference from within the UEFI setup that differentiates the two drives from the point of view of the BIOS.  I tried again but explicitly added the second drive into the UEFI section of the BIOS and it works.

Even though the drives are identical and have fresh installs of Ubuntu 16 LTS, each of the drives has to be listed uniquely and separately in the UEFI section of the bios.  This is the solution I'm going with.

Also strange, separately if I put the drives into a USB enclosure (which is not a long term solution) and connected them via USB, I didn't need to do this at all and yet it worked.

Comment: If the BIOS makes a little troubles, IMO, it is the better solution in this case. I've read few times that the EFI mode make sense with disks larger than 3TB.